# How to i convert the data in the database to JSON in a different format?

Tags: java

This is the data I created in my database

```
{   
  "id": 1,
  "values": "80,90",
  "name": "number"
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "values": "22351,25252,27123,29123,32123",
  "name": "numbers_1"
},
{
  "id": 3,
  "values": "12351,15252,17123,19123,12123",
  "name": "numbers_2"
}
```

I want to make the data saved in the above database in JSON format with Java as follows. How can I do that?

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "highNumber": "80",
  "numbers": [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "numbersCode": "22351,25252,27123,29123,32123"
    }
  ]

},
{
  "id": 2,
  "highNumber": "90",
  "numbers": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "numbersCode": "22351,25252,27123,29123,32123"
    }
  ]

}
```

I wrote the JDBC connection code, but I don't know how to write what in the while, can you help?

I wrote the JDBC connection code, but I don't know how to write what in the while, can you help?

```
public List<Number> getAllNumber() {
    List<Number> list = new ArrayList<>();


    try {
        Class.forName("DriverClass");
        Connection conn = JDBCUtils.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {
            String number= rs.getString("VALUES");
            System.out.println(number);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return list;
}
```

What I want to do is return these numbers "22351,25252,27123,29123,32123" for number 80, return these numbers "22351,25252,27123,29123,32123" for number 90.

Comment: Do you know how to parse json in Java and how to format a pojo to json again? If not, I'd suggest you start looking into that - there are multiple tutorials on the net that cover this. If you already know how to do the conversion then please share your attempt as well as the logic/rules how the 1st json should be converted to the 2nd.

Comment: I don't know, I wouldn't have asked if I knew

Comment: Result of a quick search: https://www.baeldung.com/java-org-json, other options would be libraries like Jackson or Gson. Start with those to learn about pojo <-> json conversion

Comment: I've looked here, but I don't think it will help me get the format I want. Do you have any solution?

Comment: Why don't you think it doesn't help you? You basically need to convert json-> pojo -> pojo -> json so use those as a start. The rules of the pojo -> pojo conversion is what you have to come up with since you know the source and target formats. If you don't know the rules yet try to map them out on paper, i.e. try to come up with instructions for another human on how to do it - then post those instructions here if you're still stuck.

Comment: Btw, you might want to take a [tour] and read [help] resources, especially [ask].

Comment: I'm new to java and I'm trying to learn the general syntax structure. In order to learn its logic, I need to see an example in practice, so I asked how the solution of such an example should be.

Comment: If you are new to Java I'd suggest you work through simple tutorials first and then put them together. Start with simple pojo->json and json->pojo, then combine those. Or start even earlier with a tutorial on Java's data structures. Giving you an example here might not help that much and it's hard to help if we don't know the rules of the mapping.

Comment: I need help in practice what is the solution to my question?